# Autofocusing on QLineEdit in QDialog with Popup flag and modality over main window

Tags: c++, qt, focus, taskbar, qdialog

I have a `QDialog` based class that contains `QLineEdit` and some buttons. It is invoked with context menu event from `QGraphicsScene` I would like it to behave as follows:

1. Autofocus on `QLineEdit` when invoked ( `ui->lineEdit->setFocus()` is present in constructor)
2. No taskbar icon and no frame (as for `Qt::Popup` flag)
3. Modality over main window as for `parent=0`

Using `parent = 0` fulfils 1 and provides modality but also frame and taskbar icon.

`Qt::Popup` alone removes both frame and taskbar icon but also destroys focusing on `lineEdit` and modality.

I will be grateful for any suggestions as I've lot of time over it trying to find right combination of different `WindowFlags` etc. Main problem seems to be that when any `WindowFlag` is applied or `parent` widget is defined the focusing on `lineEdit` is completely lost.

```
void GraphicsScene::resolveContextMenuAction_(QAction *action)
{
    if(action == this->contextMenuEventOpenDialog_)
    {
        TestDialog* DWD = new TestDialog(0);

        //this->DWD->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup)

        int result = DWD->exec();

        ...
    }
 }
```

Constructor:

```
TestDialog::TestDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::TestDialog)
{
  this->ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
}
```

Also the focus tab order was adjusted so that `lineEdit` is first one. In the worst case I would accept no modality as with `Qt::Popup` if only the other features mentioned are there.

In case it is OS dependant - I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

How about try setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool).
do not call exec() which is not a good way , call setModal(true) then show() instead which will show a modal dialog , and call activateWindow to setfocus to a tool window.the lineeidt will auto be focused .
if your don't want a window's frame and border, rty Qt::FramelessWindowHint flag.
Call setFocus in constructor does no use.